# Getting issue while monitoring the .docx file changes

Tags: python, docx, file-monitoring

I am trying to monitor the .docx file with the python code as follows

```
    hDir = win32file.CreateFile (
  dirPath,
  FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY,
  win32con.FILE_SHARE_READ | win32con.FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
  None,
  win32con.OPEN_EXISTING,
  win32con.FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
  None
)

while 1:
    # Wait for a change to occur
    results = win32file.ReadDirectoryChangesW (
                                               hDir,
                                               1024,
                                               False,
                                               win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE,
                                               None,
                                               None
                                               )
```

When I am trying to capture the changes made to the file, filename is coming with the temporary file names of ms word document. How to capture these temporary file changes in python.

Comment: WatchDog can do that for you: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog

Comment: On which file this watchdog should run?. I will open different word documents and do changes in it. Actually when I am monitoring the word document file, getting some temp file path.

Comment: The watchdog should run on the whole folder you are tracking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works with the following code. If we can monitor the FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SECURITY event then we can able to track all the temporary file changes also.

```
 readFlags = win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME  | \
        win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME   | \
        win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES | \
        win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE       | \
        win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE | \
        win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SECURITY
# Wait for new data and call ProcessNewData for each new chunk that's written
while 1:
    # Wait for a change to occur
    results = win32file.ReadDirectoryChangesW (
                                               hDir,
                                               1024,
                                               False,
                                               readFlags,
                                               None
                                               )
```